# An error in key Down function

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keydown

I am working with c# windows application and i need to enter some record to database after inserting in to textbox. I have tried this code

```
private void textBoxItemCode_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("You have entered the correct key.");
    }

}
```

but i am getting an error near e.KeyCode so how to make it

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: system.Eventargs does not contain a definition for key code and no Extension method keycode. this is my error

Comment: Change `EventArgs e` to `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Should be like this :-

```
private void textBoxItemCode_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered the correct key.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the following args

```
System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs
```

Your handler should look like this

```
private void textBoxItemCode_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered the correct key.");
    }

}
```

That way you have access to the `KeyCode` property which does not exist on the base `EventArgs`

Comment: that is not what you posted, Look at the method signature that you posted. You are using the base `EventArgs`

Comment: You mean base base `EventArgs` ;), sorry for correcting again.

Comment: @Silvermind I need more coffee

Comment: @user2979006 have you updated your method signature?

Comment: thanks all. special thanks to @DavidPilkington

Comment: Glad to help but out of interest sakes, why did you unaccept?